# Distribute association over a list

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, rule

I have a list `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` which I would like to associate to another list `{a,b,c}` by the rule `{1->a,2->a,3->b,4->b,5->c,6->c}`

What is the best way to do this without explicitly writing out the associations?

```
 Table[Rule[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}[[i]], {a, b, c}[[Ceiling[i/2]]]], {i, 1, 6}]
```

works but is it the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AssociationThread[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, Transpose[{{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}] // Flatten]

(* <|1 -> a, 2 -> a, 3 -> b, 4 -> b, 5 -> c, 6 -> c|> *)
```

Comment: Also, `AssociationThread[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
 Table[#, 2] & /@ {a, b, c} // Flatten]`

Answer (score 2):

```
AssociationThread[#, Riffle[#2, #2]] &[Range[6], {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
>  <|1 -> a, 2 -> a, 3 -> b, 4 -> b, 5 -> c, 6 -> c|>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
listA = {a,b,c}
listB = Riffle[listA,listA]
MapThread[Rule[#1, #2]&, {Range[6], listB}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
ClearAll[distributeAssociation];
distributeAssociation[list1_, list2_] :=
 With[{n = Length@list2},
  Join @@ MapThread[AssociationThread, {
      Partition[list1, Ceiling[Length@list1/n]],
      list2}] /; Positive[n]];
distributeAssociation[_, {}] = {};

distributeAssociation[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {a, b, c}]
(* <|1 -> a, 2 -> a, 3 -> b, 4 -> b, 5 -> c, 6 -> c|> *)
```